# Getting and using return value from stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

It's my first "system" and I'm trying to make a login in Visual Studio 2015/vb.net

I have this procedure:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[buscar_acceso]
    @login as varchar(50),
    @password as varchar(50)
as
    declare @returnvalue int

    Select acceso
    From Usuario
    Where login = @login and password = @password

    return @returnvalue
```

It returns 1 or 0 depending of the value of the login

I don't know how to code a function like "When the log-in button is pressed, you must receive the "username" and "password" parameters, use them to execute the procedure "select" and return 1 or 0. Then, if the value is 1, the"X Menu tooltip is disabled".

Thanks

Comment: It's not "a function" it's a bunch of little things that need to be done. Deconstruct the requirement into tiny requirement. Build each one and test them one at a time. That you should have requirement similar to "1) Can you show a login button, 2) Can you catch the press event, 3) Can you get the username, 4) Can you get the password, 5) Can you connect to a database, 6) Can you call the store proc, 7) Can you get the return value, 8) Can you do logic on the returned value, 9) Can you disable a menu tooltip, ..."

Comment: Stored procedures have a return. The will always be an int and is NOT intended to return values. It is intended to return a status indicator of the execution. You should use an OUTPUT parameter if you want scalar values returned. Also, you need to store passwords as salted and hashed values instead of plain text like you have going on here.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to write a sproc that will return a 1 or 0 depending on whether the record was found? How to access this return value from a sproc? How to create a web page that displays fields for user name and password? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

an efficient  way to do that in VB.net, is create a stored procedure that SELECT a single row and column - then execute the command in VB.net as 'ExecuteScalar'

e.g

```
dim LoginResult as integer = cmd.ExecuteScalar
```

.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[buscar_acceso]
@login as varchar(50),
@password as varchar(50)
as

Select CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 0 
                                    From Usuario
                                    Where login=@login and password=@password)
                        THEN 
                            1
                        ELSE
                            0
                        END
```

try something like that